# Is it possible to downgrade from php 7.4.5 to php 7.4.3

Tags: apache2, mysql, php, 20.04

yesterday I downloaded the new ubuntu 20 version and long story short it blew up my mysql and php installation; I have managed to fix some of the errors already but it looks like ubuntu upgraded me from php 7.4.3 to 7.4.5 and now my *mysql_pdo* driver is broken, I figured that I needed to install the *php7.4-gd* to make the driver to work but I cant, since it is not compatible for php 7.4.5.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-gd

php7.4-gd : Depends: php7.4-common (= 7.4.3-4ubuntu1) but 7.4.5-1+ubuntu19.10.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
```

So, is there any way to downgrade fron php 7.4.5 to 7.4.3.

EDIT: SOLVED
At the end I decided to remove php-commom and reinstall it. This solved the problem.

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove php-common
sudo apt-get install php-common php-mysql php-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

To install an older version of a package, you can use the following syntax:

```
sudo apt install PackageName=Version
```

From your question, it looks like you want to install version `7.4.3-4ubuntu1`, so you would run:

```
sudo apt install php7.4-common=7.4.3-4ubuntu1
```

That will install version `7.4.3-4ubuntu1`, however having multiple versions of the same package installed may in some cases cause conflict or `apt` may refuse to install it at all. If this is the case, you would most likely have to uninstall the current version of the package first.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt knew that you could specify the version like that, very handy.

Comment: this is issue Version '7.1.16-33ubuntu1' for 'php7.1-common' was not found, any idea